# Tail truncating doesn't work on custom Xamarin.iOS table view cells

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

In my CustomTableViewCell class I set the LineBreakMode like so:

```
protected override void CreateView()
{
    base.CreateView();

    SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;

    myLabel = new UILabel
    {
        Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(17f, UIFontWeight.Regular),
        LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.TailTruncation
    };
  
    myImageView = new UIImageView(new UIImage("myImage.png"));

    BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;

    ContentView.AddSubviews(myImageView, myLabel);
    ContentView.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();
}
```

I would like to see "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet c...".
But it doesn't seem to work, the result is the following:

[image]

Update: When I try to set the width of the label like this:

```
myLabel = new UILabel
{
    Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(17f, UIFontWeight.Regular),
    LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.TailTruncation,
    Frame.Size.Width = 100.0
};
```

I get errors:

> Cannot modify the return value of 'CGRect.Size' because it is not a variable
>
> Invalid initializer member declarator

Any ideas, how to fix it?

Comment: Make sure that you set the size of the label correctly . Can you provide the full code of `CreateView` ?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Yes, added it.

Comment: You should set the **Frame** of label like `Frame = new CGRect(50,10,100,40)` because `Frame.Size.Width` is readonly .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I use [Cirrious.FluentLayout](https://github.com/FluentLayout/Cirrious.FluentLayout) to create layouts, and I forgot to set *myLabel.AtRightOf()* in the overridden *CreateConstraints()* method. 
Using this, it's working correctly:

```
protected override void CreateConstraints()
{
    base.CreateConstraints();
    ContentView.AddConstraints(
      ...
      myLabel.AtRightOf(ContentView, 10),
      ...
    );   
}
```